# Collision Detection Not working in Game of Pac-Man

Tags: javascript, html, css, runtime-error, pacman

> I am making my own game of pac-man and am having difficulty getting
>   the collision detection between my surrounding div and the "pac-man".
>
> Here is the css for my the character (which is a square for now) and
>   the border surrounding the entire game.

```
div#pac{
    background-color: white;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 90px;
    top: 135px;
    margin: 2px;
}
div#shell{
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 80%;
    height: 75%;
    top: 85px;
    left: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #DEB887;
}
```

> next I thought I should show you the html although it is pretty basic

```
<div id="shell">
<div id="pac"></div>
</div>
```

> finally the javascript. which is where the problem starts, and it can
>   be quite complicated for some to follow.Also I use my own functions that 
>   I made called getStyle and setStyle which do exactly what they sound
>   like they do.

```
//move function for pac-man.
function move() {
    var upDown = parseInt(getStyle("pac", "top"));
    var leftRight = parseInt(getStyle("pac","left"));
    var width = parseInt(getStyle("shell", "width")) - parseInt(getStyle("pac", "width"));
    var height = parseInt(getStyle("shell", "height")) - parseInt(getStyle("pac", "height"));

    //arrow keys move down
    if (arrowKey == 40) {
        upDown = upDown + 2;
    }
    //arrow keys move up
    else if (arrowKey == 38) {
        upDown = upDown - 2;
    }    
    else if (arrowKey == 37) { //arrow keys move left
        leftRight = leftRight - 2;
    }
    else if (arrowKey == 39) { //arrow keys move right
        leftRight = leftRight + 2;
    }
    if (contains("pac", "shell")) {
        //arrow keys bounce from frame down
        if (upDown <= 85) {
            upDown += 2;
        }
        else if (upDown >= height + 35) {
            upDown += -2;
        }
        else if (leftRight <= 130){
            leftRight += 2;
        }
        else if (leftRight >= width + 35){
            leftRight += -2;
        }
    }
    //update to new location
    setStyle("pac", "top", upDown + "px");
    setStyle("pac", "left", leftRight + "px");
}
```

> in the function above I start by defining my variables.
>
> next I create the actual movement function to tell it to move in a
>   certain direction when a certain key is pressed.
>
> then I do my collision testing which is where the problem occurs.
>
> this problem is very erratic and random. when I run the function the
>   collision detection between the top and the left works just fine. but
>   when I try to move to the right or bottom sides of the surrounding div
>   it cuts me off about 50-80 pixels short.
>
> and you would think just add like 50-80 more pixels to the detection
>   but NOPE that's when it gets even weirder because if I add any more
>   pixels to it, the collision detection just disappears and the pac-man
>   is able to fly right off the screen like there is no div there at all
>
> please, anyone, I have been trying to solve this for 2 days and I
>   can't find a solution. Am I missing something obvious? I tried
>   changing some of the css to stuff like position relative and the left
>   and top attributes but nothing helped.
>
> the full source code and the included library(which has the getStyle
>   and setStyle function is below)
>   https://github.com/nicholaskorte/Javascript-pac-man-game/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found my own answer.
>
> The issue resided within the containing function within my library.
>
> i changed this...

```
function contains(id1, id2) {
    var left1 = parseInt(getStyle(id1, "left"));
    var top1 = parseInt(getStyle(id1, "top"));
    var width1 = parseInt(getStyle(id1, "width"));
    var width2 = parseInt(getStyle(id2, "width"));
    var height1 = parseInt(getStyle(id1, "height"));
    var height2 = parseInt(getStyle(id2, "height"));

    if (left1 <= 5) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (left1 > width2 - width1) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (top1 < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (top1 > height2 - height1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> to this...

```
function collisionFrame(id1, id2) {
    var left1 = parseInt(getStyle(id1, "left"));
    var right1 = left1 + parseInt(getStyle(id1, "width"));
    var top1 = parseInt(getStyle(id1, "top"));
    var bottom1 = top1 + parseInt(getStyle(id1, "height"));

    var left2 = parseInt(getStyle(id2, "left"));
    var right2 = left2 + parseInt(getStyle(id2, "width"));
    var top2 = parseInt(getStyle(id2, "top"));
    var bottom2 = top2 + parseInt(getStyle(id2, "height"));

    if (left1 < left2 + 4) {//from left
        return false;
    }
    else if (right1 > right2 - 4) {//from right
        return false;
    }
    if (top1 < top2 + 4) {//from top
        return false;
    }
    if (bottom1 > bottom2 - 4) {//from bottom
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> ...and it worked